# IIS 7.5 , Website with multiple binding response is interchanged

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7.5

I have a Asp.Net MVC3 WebSite in IIS 7.5 with following bindings,

```
http mywebsite1 80
http mywebsite2 80
```

Based on the Url "`http://mywebsite1/`" or "`http://mywebsite2/`" i am setting up the HttpContext parameters and thread culture.

When I deploy the website and browse both the url simultaneously , response from one website is visible in another. But in subsequent refresh corresponding contents are loaded.

Can any one please tell, what might be the issue?
Is it problem with IIS or MVC application?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your application rather than IIS. Can't really go into anymore detail without some more info :-)

Comment: But if it is an application issue, why it is happening only first time not on subsequent requests.